# How to sign and convert integers in Javascript, output to HTML canvas, and reverse process?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, colors, png

I'm attempting to convert images (using HTML canvas) from RGB to the YCoCg colour space, and save the output from canvas as a PNG, which can be converted back losslessly, based on code from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12146329/2399347

The process is reversible, but my attempt only currently works when an intermediate format isn't used. Without this, the code has limited practical application.

I need to get the 'lifting' process to use 8-bit signed integers (I believe from -128 to 127, modulo 0x100 in the pseudocode), and convert the values to be displayed on canvas (from 0 to 255), before being able to save. If successful, when the converted image is placed in canvas, reconverting the values and reverse lifting should produce the original image. The values currently generated can't correctly be displayed on canvas (from -255 to 255).

The above problem is beyond my current knowledge, and I haven't found a way of doing it so far based on online searches and looking at Javascript documentation. Those who know (or are interested), could you please look at the code, and suggest or give a practical way of doing this, or workaround to that effect?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="charset=UTF-8" />
    <style>
    img, canvas {
        display: block;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
function go() {

//  Extract PNG image to Canvas

    var canvas = document.getElementById('ycocg');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var source = document.querySelector("#original");

    canvas.width = source.width;
    canvas.height = source.height;

    ctx.drawImage(source, 0, 0);

    var canvasData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


//  Canvas to convert image to YCoCg and back in one step

    var canvasBack = document.getElementById('back2rgb');
    var ctxBack = canvasBack.getContext('2d');

    canvasBack.width = source.width;
    canvasBack.height = source.height;

    ctxBack.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

    var canvasBackData = ctxBack.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


//  Colour space functions

function forward_lift( x1, y1 ) {
    var diff = ( ( y1 - x1 ) ) % 256;
    var average = ( x1 + ( diff >> 1 ) ) % 256;

    return  { c1: average, c2: diff };
}

function reverse_lift( average, diff ) {
    var x2 = ( average - ( diff >> 1 ) ) % 256;
    var y2 = ( ( x2 + diff ) ) % 256;

    return  { c1: x2, c2: y2 };
}

function RGB_to_YCoCg24( red, green, blue ) {
    // Conversion and back

    var lift1 = forward_lift( red, blue );
    var lift2 = forward_lift( green, lift1.c1 );

    var rlift1 = reverse_lift( lift2.c1, lift2.c2 );
    var rlift2 = reverse_lift( rlift1.c2, lift1.c2 );

    canvasBackData.data[idx + 0] = rlift2.c1 % 256; // R
    canvasBackData.data[idx + 1] = rlift1.c1 % 256; // G
    canvasBackData.data[idx + 2] = rlift2.c2 % 256; // B

    // Attempt at conversion only and store

    canvasData.data[idx + 0] = lift2.c1 % 256; // Y
    canvasData.data[idx + 1] = lift2.c2 % 256; // Cg
    canvasData.data[idx + 2] = lift1.c2 % 256; // Co
}

function YCoCg24_to_RGB( Yimg, Cg, Co ) {
    // Attempt at reversing stored image

    var rlift1 = reverse_lift( Yimg, Cg );
    var rlift2 = reverse_lift( rlift1.c2, Co );

    canvasStepData.data[idx + 0] = rlift2.c1 % 256; // R
    canvasStepData.data[idx + 1] = rlift1.c1 % 256; // G
    canvasStepData.data[idx + 2] = rlift2.c2 % 256; // B
}

//  Conversion of RGB image to YCoCg

    for (var x = 0; x < canvasData.width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < canvasData.height; y++) {
            // Index of the pixel in the array
            var idx = (x + y * canvas.width) * 4;

            RGB_to_YCoCg24( canvasData.data[idx + 0], canvasData.data[idx + 1], canvasData.data[idx + 2]  );
        }
    }
    ctxBack.putImageData(canvasBackData, 0, 0);
    ctx.putImageData(canvasData, 0, 0);


//  Convert from YCoCg to RGB, in two steps

    var canvasStep = document.getElementById('twostep');
    var ctxStep = canvasStep.getContext('2d');

    canvasStep.width = source.width;
    canvasStep.height = source.height;

    ctxStep.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

    var canvasStepData = ctxStep.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (var x = 0; x < canvasData.width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < canvasData.height; y++) {
            // Index of the pixel in the array
            var idx = (x + y * canvas.width) * 4;

            YCoCg24_to_RGB( canvasStepData.data[idx + 0], canvasStepData.data[idx + 1], canvasStepData.data[idx + 2]  );
        }
    }
    ctxStep.putImageData(canvasStepData, 0, 0);
}
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="go()">

<div id="container">
    Original:
    <img id="original" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />

    Converted and back in one step:
    <canvas id="back2rgb"></canvas>

    Converted and stored (right click, save image as):
    <canvas id="ycocg"></canvas>

    Restored previous image:
    <canvas id="twostep"></canvas>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```