# Conversion from YCCK / CMYK to BGRA color space with libjpeg-turbo

Tags: c++, image-processing, color-space, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

I have a YCCK image on my input and I use libjpeg-turbo to first convert it to CMYK and then I manually convert CMYK to BGRA. I am doing this because I have read somewhere that direct conversion from YCCK to BGRA is not supported by libjpeg-turbo.

This is my current conversion algorithm:

```cpp
auto const rowStride{ jpegDecompressWrapper.cinfo().output_width * jpegDecompressWrapper.cinfo().output_components };

JSAMPARRAY buffer{ ( *( cinfo ).mem->alloc_sarray )( reinterpret_cast< j_common_ptr >( &( jpegDecompressWrapper.cinfo() ) ), JPOOL_IMAGE, rowStride, 1 ) };

while ( cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height )
{
    jpeg_read_scanlines( &cinfo, buffer, 1 );
    for ( std::size_t i{ 0U }; i < rowStride / 4; ++i )
    {
        auto const c{ static_cast< std::uint8_t >( buffer[ 0 ][ i * 4U      ] ) };
        auto const m{ static_cast< std::uint8_t >( buffer[ 0 ][ i * 4U + 1U ] ) };
        auto const y{ static_cast< std::uint8_t >( buffer[ 0 ][ i * 4U + 2U ] ) };
        auto const k{ static_cast< std::uint8_t >( buffer[ 0 ][ i * 4U + 3U ] ) };

        // Convert CMYK to RGB
        auto const r{ static_cast< std::uint8_t >( ( ( 255 - c ) * ( 255 - k ) ) / 255 ) };
        auto const g{ static_cast< std::uint8_t >( ( ( 255 - m ) * ( 255 - k ) ) / 255 ) };
        auto const b{ static_cast< std::uint8_t >( ( ( 255 - y ) * ( 255 - k ) ) / 255 ) };

        // Assign RGB values to the same pixel
        pOutput[ i * 4U      ] = b;
        pOutput[ i * 4U + 1U ] = g;
        pOutput[ i * 4U + 2U ] = r;
        pOutput[ i * 4U + 3U ] = 255;
    }

    pOutput += rowStride;
}
```

It's pretty poor because I get too dark image on the output.

Does anyone know how can I improve my algorithm or if it's possible to directly convert YCCK to BGRA with libjpeg-turbo?

Comment: Converting between color-spaces is nontrivial: you also need to consider things like gamma correction, and the different kinds of RGB color-spaces (e.g. sRGB vs Adobe RGB vs Linear RGB). BTW, you should remove the `static_cast` to `uint8_t` because it means you'll lose precision: you should probably be using `double` to represent intermediate values.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566668/lossless-rgb-to-ycbcr-transformation

Comment: yes, i know it's non-trivial. Do you know if libjpeg does support this kind of conversion or not?

Comment: Which version of `libjpeg` are you using?

Comment: actually, i am using libjpeg-turbo, version 2.1.4

Comment: and `static_cast`s will eventually be needed when assigning each component so i don't think that's a mistake in above code

Comment: Your arithmetic operations like `( ( 255 - c ) * ( 255 - k ) ) / 255` will be conducted over integral types, which truncate values and lose precision berfore the final values are obtained. At least give it a try first to eliminate that.

Comment: ¿What are the input ranges of cmyk components? The formula used assumes that they are in 0...255 range, but I suspect that may not be the case. 0...100 range is possible.

Comment: @Dai i get the same thing without casts

Comment: @user7860670 i am not sure but i can maybe check

Comment: Going from CMYK to RGB is non-trivial like Dai says -- there's not only no single "RGB", but also way more versions of CMYK (ink and paper differ). You would get much better luck if you just had an actual ICC library do the job. If you don't want to do that, just be informed that your current algorithm is basically the same as jpeg-turbo's cmyk.c, so play around with Levels in GIMP to figure out the correct gamma & ranges.

Comment: @MingyeWang so libjpeg-turbo doesn't do anything smarter than what i've written in the question?

Comment: @NutCracker correct, it doesn't!

Comment: disappointing :(